# Adding an image in the padding area of the video instead of black color using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have some videos of resolution 1280 X 720 with black padding area in both left and right side around the display area of all videos. I want to display a static image in padding area of video instead of solid black color. I am working with FFMPEG library but can't find any way to do so. Can you please help me regarding this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) filter to determine crop parameters to remove the black. See [Remove black bars using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/810524/) for an example of how to get the crop parameters.
2. [Crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) the black area and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) the video over the image:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0]crop=404:720:438:0[vid];[1][vid]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -c:a copy output.mp4
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying some commands I made a command to do so and its working for me.

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:-1[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1" output.mp4